# feature scaling and intercept

Tags: octave, normalization

it is a beginner question but I have a dataset of two features house sizes and number of bedrooms, So I'm working on Octave; So basically I try to do a feature scaling but as in the Design Matrix I added A column of ones (for tetha0) So I try to do a mean normalisation : (x- mean(x)/std(x) 
but in the columns of one obviously the mean is 1 since there is only 1 in every line So when I do this the intercept colum is set to 0 :

```
 mu = mean(X)
mu =

  1.0000   2000.6809      3.1702

 votric = X - mu
votric =

  0.00000    103.31915     -0.17021
  0.00000   -400.68085     -0.17021
  0.00000    399.31915     -0.17021
  0.00000   -584.68085     -1.17021
  0.00000    999.31915      0.82979
```

So the first column shouldn't be left out of the mean normalization ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're supposed to normalise the original dataset over all observations first, and only then add the bias term (i.e. the 'column of ones').

The point of normalisation is to allow the various features to be compared on an equal basis, which speeds up optimization algorithms significantly.

The bias (i.e. column of ones) is technically not part of the features. It is just a mathematical convenience to allow us to use a single matrix multiplication to obtain our result in a computationally and notationally efficient manner.

In other words, instead of saying `Y = bias + weight1 * X1 + weight2 * X2` etc, you create an imaginary `X0 = 1`, and denote the bias as `weight0`, which then allows you to express it in a vectorised fashion as follows: `Y = weights * X`

"Normalising" the bias term does not make sense, because clearly that would make `X0 = 0`, the effect of which would be that you would then discard the effect of the bias term altogether. So yes, normalise first, and only then add 'ones' to the normalised features.

---

PS. I'm going on a limb here and guessing that you're coming from Andrew Ng's machine learning course on coursera. You will see in ex1_multi.m that this is indeed what he's doing in his code (line 52).

```
% Scale features and set them to zero mean
fprintf('Normalizing Features ...\n');

[X mu sigma] = featureNormalize(X);

% Add intercept term to X
X = [ones(m, 1) X];
```

Comment: hey! thank you for the explanation and I'm amazed by your Medium skills, yes the course is by andrew Ng ( how did you know that ? ) but it's not from Coursera It is a collection of pdf I found on git hub . Ill go check it on coursera too thanks for the help

Comment: There are so many people asking octave questions that come from that course, that I've decided to take it myself so that I can know what they're talking about half the time when their question doesn't make full sense, ahahah. I recognised the "houses and bedrooms" problem. Yes, it's a good course, do it!